# Вопрос с STEAM API

Tags: php, api, steam

Возникла проблема. Использую [это](https://github.com/halipso/php-steam-tradeoffers) и возник вопрос, как мне узнать **cookies** и какие нужно, если с **sessionid** все понятно, но с **webCookie** нет?

Answer (score 0):

Если уж берете чей-то код для использования то внимательно читайте описание к нему. Данный форк основан на https://github.com/Alex7Kom/node-steam-tradeoffers и использует его функции, тот в свою очередь использует https://github.com/seishun/node-steam и https://github.com/Alex7Kom/node-steam-weblogon

В `node-steam-weblogon` прямо кусок кода приведен как получить интересующие Вас `webSessionID` и `cookies`

```js
steamClient.on('logOnResponse', function(logonResp) {
  if (logonResp.eresult == Steam.EResult.OK) {
    steamWebLogOn.webLogOn(function(webSessionID, cookies){
      ...
    });
  }
});
```